# I can't build project in release mode

Tags: c#-4.0, msbuild, c#-2.0, sgen

I can build project in debug mode, when I change to Release mode show this message:

**The assembly mix mode was compiled in relation of version 'v2.0.50727' in runtime and do not be loaded in runtime 4.0 without configuration of additional information**

File: **SGEN**

I don't have this file and I don't know what I can do.

Comment: Solution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2572158

Add the infomation below to the sgen.exe.config file located at the following location: ..\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\

```
       <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
           <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
      </startup>
```